# Move child element above parent element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Input XML is like as

```
<figure id="f1_1">    
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626233614_c001_f001.jpg"/>
<legend><para>Reeve’s prosthesis. (Reproduced with permission from Reeves B, Jobbins B, Dowson D, Wright V. A Total Shoulder Endo-Prosthesis.</para></legend>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

Output should be

```
<figure id="f1_1">
<legend><para>Reeve’s prosthesis. (Reproduced with permission from Reeves B, Jobbins B, Dowson D, Wright V. A Total Shoulder Endo-Prosthesis.</para></legend>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626233614_c001_f001.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

I have wrote XSLT like as,

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::legend">
            <xsl:variable name="a1" select="following-sibling::legend"/>                    
            <xsl:copy-of select="$a1"/>
            <xsl:copy>                        
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>                    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It's not reflecting proper output. Can you help us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
    <xsl:copy-of select="legend"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except legend"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Rupesh. It's working properly.

Comment: We have below mentioned instance where above mentioned xslt is not working properly.
<figure id="c001_f002" counter="yes">
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002a.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002b.jpg"/>
<legend><para>Fig. 1-2 Keloid scar.</para></legend>
</subfigure>
</figure>In this case "legend" element should be move to above of both "subfigure" elements which is under "figure".But while using above mentioned xslt, the legend is appearing between the two "subfigure" elements.

Comment: Could you guide us, how to write code in this case.